# Can you print to a specific column in awk?

Tags: awk

I've begun doing things in awk for file comparisons.  Is there a way to print data to a specific column?  The book I am using does not touch upon this in the print section and I can't seem to find exactly what I am looking for.

Let's say I wanted to print a line, but also print a string ("test") inside of a specific blank column[$12].  Can I do that?  Thanks for any help

```
{print $0, "test"[$12]}
```

Comment: Unless you are reading the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins, throw that book away. If you are reading the correct book then it does tell you what you want to know.

Answer (score 3):

you can overwrite existing fields easily

```
$ awk '... {$12="test"; print}' file
```

if you have your code and sample input output people can suggest better ways since usually what you ask for is not what you really need.

e.g.

```
$ echo 'a,b,c, ,e' | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$4="test"; print}'

a,b,c,test,e
```

`awk` will also extend (add missing fields) if add to an index higher than what you currently have

```
$ echo 'a,b,c, ,e' | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$12="test"; print}'

a,b,c, ,e,,,,,,,test
```

also you can shorten the code by replacing print with `1`, such as

```
... '{$4="test"}1'
```